# Zsh bookmark directories with tab completion?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

What I want:

`cd c/ra<tab>` completes to `~/code/rails-app` and `cd c/<tab>` shows a list of dirs within `~/code`

What I currently have:

`c ra<tab>` completes to `c rails-app` if I have a directory `~/code/rails-app` and `c <tab>` shows a list of dirs within `~/code`

By having this in my `.zshrc`:

```
c() { cd ~/code/$1; }
_c() { _files -W ~/code -/; }
compdef _c c
```

This tool looks promising: https://github.com/flavio/jump but I'd like something more lightweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab completion such as you've described, at least for directories, should be doable by `zsh` without the need to write a `zsh` function.

[This link](http://scottlinux.com/2011/08/19/quick-intro-to-zsh-auto-complete/), for example, notes that typing `/u/l/b` then <kbd>tab</kbd> expands to `/usr/local/bin` on the prompt.

This works for me - if I make a directory `~/code/rails-app` such:

```
zsh% ls ~/code
another-app       another-dir rails-app
zsh% ls ~/code/rails-app
one two
```

then:

```
zsh% cd c/ra<TAB> # this expands to 'cd code/rails-app'
zsh% cd c/<TAB><TAB> # Double tab, one to expand "c" to "code", 
zsh% #               # second gives me the zsh-completion menu
```

I can't point out which `zsh` option this is - I'm using a fairly heavily modified `~/.zshrc` and bits of [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). This *might* be functionality given by `zsh` without needing to be enabled; if not, details in either the first link or somewhere in `oh-my-zsh` or even [some version of the ZSH manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/) should help. (I find the manual a little ... overwhelming, to say the least, though).

I don't believe that you need to write a function to achieve this behaviour - `zsh` is definitely able to do it.

Comment: I settled on using fasd https://github.com/clvv/fasd which is a different way to solve my problem. But thanks, your exactly right Zsh autocomplete has most of the features I was requesting.